# How to encapsulate a model into the sklearn base estimator?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I have read few articles explaining how to create your own custom model using `sklearn BaseEstimator class`, but the thing is that I need to use a regression model from the [darts api](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/generated_api/darts.models.forecasting.html), and in order to optimize its hyperparameters, the model must be a sklearn estimator, so I have to find a way to encapsulate the darts model (for example, `LightGBMModel`), into a `sklearn.base.BaseEstimator`.

Below is an example of how I tried:

```py
from darts.models import LightGBMModel
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator

class MyLightGBM(BaseEstimator, LightGBMModel):
    def __init__(self, lags=4, random_state=0):
        self.lags = lags
        self.random_state=random_state

    ...
```

Sklearn needs the `fit()` and `predict()` methods, but the darts `LightGBMModel` already has these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it with catboost's regressor and this works:

```
class MyCatBoost(CatBoostRegressor, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, random_state=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.random_state = random_state
```

Look up MRO(method resolution order) in python to learn why I have changed the order or inheritance.